# Replacing First Space with new line mysql

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a mysql query where i can replace first occurrence of Space in a string with a new line.

For example,

```
LSRNABC1234 This is a sample
```

So here I wish to insert new line after `LSRNABC1234` so resulting string would look like:

```
LSRNABC1234 
This is a sample
```

The regular find and replace queries replace everything, I am not sure how to insert new line just after first space.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET text = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ' ', 1),
                  CHAR(10 using utf8),     -- line break
                  SUBSTRING(text, INSTR(text, ' ') + 1));
```

Here is a demo showing that the string manipulation logic is working correctly:

### Demo